# Alternative to passing down action from the top reducer to deep ancestor in redux

Tags: redux

If I have a big state, well deep rather, does that mean I have to pass actions to child reducers all the way from the top? Since it seems that all actions are global.

Let me explain. Let's say I have a structure 10 reducers deep. Then the deepest reducer have an action 'ADD_WHATEVER'. Does that mean that in the other 9 reducers I have to handle and pass on the action to the child reducer? 9 times?

Is there an alternative approach?

I mean besides avoiding having a 10 level deep structure, that was just an extreme example. I feel that I am not understanding correctly here. I hope there is an alternative way.

Like just defining the action in the deep child, and then have redux figure out it need to recreate all parent objects because it mutated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combineReducers` to separate reducers. But that doesn't really handle deep structure.

Your issue here is really about your design. Deep structures are harder to maintains and reason about. You shouldn't rely on them, there's always a better way to structure your object models in a way where they're not deep.

There's even plugins like [normalizr](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr) to help unnest deep structure when they're returned by your API.

I'd recommend considering a refactor of your structure.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that. I don't have this problem really, but evaluating redux, and wanted to understand this clearly. The example was extreme on purpose. It might be an issue though, not 10 levels, but enough to make it require a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: If you end up with a deeply nested data structure, then you have a design issue.

Comment: I agree to a certain degree, but at the same time I feel the creation of tools like normalizr hints that there is a "weekness" here. Ideally I would like for actions to only be picked up by the reducer that responds to it, and that all reducers need to implement a "CHILD_HAS_MUTATED" action, so that any parent reducers will rerun that and mutate any parent object structures to ensure that all parents to the child has also mutated. That's at least my initial thought...